# How to determine the longest increasing sub-sequence using dynamic programming with joinable input integers

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dynamic-programming, lis

I read the article about
How to determine the longest increasing sub-sequence using dynamic programming
with this algorithm:

```
int maxLength = 1, bestEnd = 0;
DP[0] = 1;
prev[0] = -1;

for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
   DP[i] = 1;
   prev[i] = -1;

   for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
      if (DP[j] + 1 > DP[i] && array[j] < array[i])
      {
         DP[i] = DP[j] + 1;
         prev[i] = j;
      }

   if (DP[i] > maxLength)
   {
      bestEnd = i;
      maxLength = DP[i];
   }
}
```

but i want to know how to solve this problem with this condition that we can take the arrays with joined integers.

```
For example: 1,5,3,1,5,6,7,8,1,2,9
we can have this set:1,3,5,6,7,8,12 for solution
that 12 is joint form 1 and 2
```

so conditions are:
The input array includes 1-9 numbers! and the integers can joined from few other integers.

Comment: How do you measure the length of the subsequence?  Would `12` count as 1 or 2 elements?

Comment: @ScottHunter the 12 is one element,
so we have 7 length set there

Comment: So in your example, `1,3,5,6,7,8,9` and `1,3,5,6,7,8,12` would both be solutions.

Comment: so all the elements of array[i] are single digit numbers?

Comment: @JohnSmith yes the input array is single digit numbers but the answer could be multiple digit array

Comment: @JohnSmith any idea?

Comment: @ScottHunter any idea?

Comment: You'll need to specify the rules for how one can take individual digits and join them.  For example, do they have to be adjacent in the array?  In a given order?  Any other constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Original problem

```
dp[i] = max(DP[j] + 1, a[j] < a[i])
```

#### Your problem

Let:

```
a[x,y] = a[x] + a[x + 1] + ... + a[y] (+ means concatenate)
```

So:

```
f[x,y] = max(DP[j] + 1, a[j] < a[x,y], j < x)
dp[i] = max(f[i,j], 0 <= j <= i) = max(
   max(DP[j] + 1, a[j] < a[i], j < i) # f(i, i)
   max(DP[j] + 1, a[j] < a[i-1, i], j < i - 1) # f(i-1, i)
   ...
)
```

If you still have some problems, please don't hesitate to leave a comment here.